# Pure JS, get element by class but not class

Tags: javascript

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
```

Gives me all the `.classname` classes, how do I update the code to get all those classes but excluding `.classname_exclude`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than using the method `.getElementsByClassName()`, you could use the [method `.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (which accepts CSS3 selectors) and use the [`:not()` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to negate those elements:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.classname:not(.classname_exclude)');
```